# UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation Delegate not calling

Tags: iphone, orientation, uipageviewcontroller

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
                 spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation

this delegate is not calling ........

i have also used

```
NSDictionary *options =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid]forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];
```

to call UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid method

UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin and UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax methods are calling..

Code runs finely when i run it seperately..... but When i integrate the code the UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid is not working and that delegate is not calling ....

Why this so......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the class ref on

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDelegate.html

that the delegate is only called if you got the transition style UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl. Probably that is your problem.

> **Discussion**
>
> Use this method to change the spine location when the device orientation changes, as well as setting new view controllers and changing the double-sided state.
> This method is called only if the transition style is UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl.